# How can I change the Windows username in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, windows-users

I created a new Windows user (mixael). And soon I deleted it. And when I needed to use SQL Server I encountered an error. I logged in under the wrong user in SQL. and because of this, I could not use diagrams. The question is, how can I change the username, when authenticating (.../Natalia)?

[image]

Comment: I didn't try but I guess you could start SSMS as a different user (shift-right-click, Run as different user...)

Comment: when I connect another windows user-it shows correctly. but when I enabled my base user-an error occurs in the form of an incorrectly displayed user

Comment: Ok, I see, one attempt I could think of: Delete the saved connection altogether, you can do this by clicking on the dropdown list for the "Server Name" and then with the list open, put the mouse over the entry and press DEL key. Then try to make a new connection to the server. This might fix wrong settings.

Comment: okey, i will try it. thank you

Comment: To connect as a different Windows User, within SSMS, you need to run the application as that other user. Normally you would do this by right clicking the application while holding shift, which will expose the "Run as a different user" dialogue window. Note that (at least historically) this feature is disabled in the Start Menu in Windows 10 and needs a registry key change to enable. Thus use a shortcut on the Desktop do this.